# Cant build collider (websocket-based signaling server in Go)

Tags: go, webrtc, collider, apprtc

Iam trying to build apprtc signaling server(collider).  Based on tutorial, we only need to enter

> go get collidermain

after setting $GOPATH. But I got error like this

```
 > go get collider/collidermain
src/collider/collidermain/main.go:9:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/abdulmanaf/poc/apprtcNewVersion/apprtc/src/collider
```

Then I had tried to build collider folder. But I got error like this

```
> go get collider/collider
# golang.org/x/net/websocket
src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/dial.go:18:19: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘tls.DialWithDialer’
   conn, err = tls.DialWithDialer(dialer, "tcp", parseAuthority(config.Location), config.TlsConfig)
```

What is the actual issue related to this? I need to build and deploy collider application

Comment: What is "collider"? Please show exactly what steps you're following. `collider/collider` isn't a go get-able url, so you may have some other incorrect import paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a really old version of go. Could you run `go version`?

`tls.DialWithDialer` was added in [go 1.3](https://golang.org/doc/go1.3#minor_library_changes) in 2014.

Comment: Sounds like default ubuntu that ships with go 1.2 indeed :(

Comment: this is due to, i have installed go from official website . but go already available in my ubuntu 14.04(using apt-get). I had just removed old version, it will be working fine. thanks for all your supports.